# New field in email

Tags: magento-1.8, email, transactional, date

I have added a **new field** in the **order process** called `desired_deliver_date`.

I can get the value of this field into the email by putting

```
 {{var order.getDesiredDeliveryDate()}}
```

However the date format is `YYYY-mm-dd`

Can someone advise whats the best way to format the date so its `dd/mm/YYYY` ?

Answer (score 1):

Add to the order object real function getDesiredDeliveryDate  that will format the date. Like

```
public function getDesiredDeliveryDate($format)
{
    return Mage::helper('core')->formatDate($this->getDesiredDeliveryDate(), $format, true);
}
```

Comment: Thanks sorry but where exactly would I put that function?

Comment: You need to rewrite the order object or copy it to local folder. See for example http://inchoo.net/magento/how_to_override_magento_model_classes/

Comment: Do you mean copy /app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Order.php to local folder and put the function in there?

Comment: Yes, it's not a super best practice, but you can do it. It's easy and fast solution.

Comment: Curious about the difference between "best practice" and "super best practice". =)

Comment: @pspahn, well it's great question =)  As you understand, moving the big Order.php class to the local folder may prevent further customizations.  So I recommend rewriting with custom module.  It also not conflicts-friendly solutions, but at least you'll see the conflicts and can resolve them.